# How can I see the contents of an MDF file?

Tags: file-format, mds

I have a file with .mdf extension, and a small .mds with the same name. What kind of format is MDF? How can I see the contents of this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Alchohol software to run this file.
http://www.alcohol-soft.com/
These are typically image files an you mount them as a virtual drive to read their contents. Whats in there and what you do with it however, thats another question.